# Let $n:\mathbb{R \to Z}$. Prove that $n(x+y)=n(x)+n(y) \implies n(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, functions

let $n$ be a function $n:\mathbb{R \to Z}$

Prove that  $n(x+y)=n(x)+n(y) \implies n(x)=0$

But I don't know how to solve it ... any hints ?

Comment: Can you use $n(x)=n(\frac{x}2+\frac{x}2)$ to calculate $n(\frac{x}2)$? If you choose some integer to be $n(x)$, try calculating $n(x/2)$ then $n(x/4)$ and $n(x/8)$ and so on. Do you see what the problem is when $n(x)$ isn't $0$?

Comment: Nice solution by Meelo. Pity the post is likely to be closed.

Comment: @ Meelo. Thank you. I solved it just now due to your advice.

Comment: This should get re-opened. @MiloBrandt's answer is very nice and intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we have
$$n(x) = a \neq 0$$

Take $b \in \mathbb{N}$

$$bn\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = n\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)+n\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)+...+n\left(\frac{x}{b}\right) = n\left(\frac{bx}{b}\right) = n(x) = a$$
a
So we see that $$n(x) = a \Rightarrow n\left(\frac{x}{b}\right) = \frac{a}{b}$$

But $a$ is an integer, and $n(x)$ can only produce integers. If we pick some $b$ which does not divide $a$ we arrive at a contradiction, so $n(x) \neq 0$ is false.

We can easily verify that $n(x) = 0$ for all $x$ satisfies $n(x+y) = n(x) + n(y)$, so it is the only solution.